# Understanding of BASIC code

Tags: basic

I need to read some basic code. I never worked with BASIC and ask you help me. There is such code

```
filedialog "Open","*.txt",file$
 if file$="" then end
open file$  for input as #f
'open "g:\data\funcfirstques.txt" for input as #f

while not(eof(#f))
  line input #f, a$
  i=i+1
wend
close #f
nrows=i

open "g:\data\junk.txt" for output as #1
print#1, a$
close #1

open "g:\data\junk.txt" for input as #1
while not(eof(#1))
input #1, b$
k=k+1
wend
close #1
```

As I understood, here is opening file **file$**, then in first loop, counting lines in this file and adding they to array **a$**. Then opening file **junk.txt** and writing array **a$** to this file. But what is doing in second loop? What is the **k**?

Input is usual .csv file.

Thanks.

P.S Sorry for my awful English :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its **reading** the file

As you know from this

```
open "g:\data\junk.txt" for output as #1
print#1, a$
close #1
```

like open for OUTPUT and PRINT #

similarly this...

```
open "g:\data\junk.txt" for input as #1
while not(eof(#1))
input #1, b$
k=k+1
wend
```

is reading the file back IN byte by byte.

Comment: OK, **i** is number of rows, what is **k**

Comment: i is number of rows and a$ is the row data
k is the byte counter and b$ is the byte data (character)
In the code block with i - the file is read in LINE by LINE
In the code block using k - the file is read in BYTE by BYTE
Line by Line is good for text data
Byte by byte is good for binary data

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** The code lets the user pick a text file and copies the last line of that file into a file named `g:\data\junk.txt` which then is read again.  `i` and `nrows` contain the number of rows of the chosen file, and `k` contains the number of comma separated entries in the last line of the chosen text file.

---

Let's see this step by step.  First, let's assume there is no code executed before this, and the BASIC dialect starts with a value of 0 for numeric variables and an empty string for string variables that are used before they got some value assigned.

```
filedialog "Open","*.txt",file$
if file$="" then end
```

The user is presented with a file dialog with a preset filter for filenames ending with `.txt`.  The chosen filename is assigned to `file$`.  The next line tests for an empty filename and ends the program in that case.  How can the user choose an empty filename?  That's the value if the user doesn't choose a name but closes the dialog with the „cancel“ button or the „x“ button.

```
open file$ for input as #f
'open "g:\data\funcfirstques.txt" for input as #f
```

The chosen file is opened in text mode for reading as file number 0 because `f` wasn't initialised before.  There is an `open` statement commented out, presumly a file for testing without the need to go through the open dialog again and again while developing the program.

```
while not(eof(#f))
  line input #f, a$
  i=i+1
wend
close #f
nrows=i
```

While it is not the end of file (`eof`) of the open file, the file is read line by line, each line assigned to the variable `a$` and the variable `i` is increased by one for each line.  `a$` is not an array like suspected in the question, but a scalar string variable.  So after the loop `a$` contains the last line read from the file.

After the loop the file is closed and `nrows`, presumably meaning „number of rows“ is assigned the number of lines counted in `i`.  It's a bit odd to not use `nrows` from the beginning to count the lines.

```
open "g:\data\junk.txt" for output as #1
print #1, a$
close #1
```

Another file, this time with a fixed name, is opened for writing, disgarding any potential previous file content, and the last line from the file chosen by the user is written as a single line into that file.  This time a fixed file number of 1 is used for opening and then closing the file.

```
open "g:\data\junk.txt" for input as #1
while not(eof(#1))
  input #1, b$
  k=k+1
wend
close #1
```

Now that file is opened again for reading.  It is read to the end of file again, but this time not line by line, which wouldn't make much sense to use a loop for, because we *know* there is exactly one line in that file.

`input` not preceded by the keyword `line` reads up to a comma or the line end.  Consuming those characters, i.e. the next `input` continues reading after the comma or line end.  So this reads a row of comma separated values, one entry at a time, counting them in the variable `k`.  Leading and trailing spaces are discarded, and it is possible to preserve those and have a comma *within* an entry by enclosing the entry in double quotes.

If the user chose a file with the following last line…

```
x,  foo  ," bar, baz ",42
```

… the value of `k` would be 4 in the end, and `b$` will be assigned `"x"`, `"foo"` (no spaces around), `" bar , baz "` (spaces around and comma within), and `"42"`.

Answer (score -1):

Corrected code for reading a file:

```
filedialog "Open","*.txt",file$
IF file$ = "" THEN END
OPEN file$ FOR INPUT AS #1
'OPEN "g:\data\funcfirstques.txt" FOR INPUT AS #1
OPEN "g:\data\junk.txt" FOR OUTPUT AS #2
WHILE NOT EOF(1)
    LINE INPUT #1, a$
    PRINT #2, a$
    i = i + 1
WEND
nrows = i
CLOSE #1, #2
OPEN "g:\data\junk.txt" FOR INPUT AS #1
WHILE NOT EOF(1)
    INPUT #1, b$
    k = k + 1
WEND
CLOSE #1
PRINT "File has"; k; " lines."
END
```